# Should good information be posted as an answer or comment?

Tags: support, answers, not-an-answer

This was [posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26491620/2982225)

> Take in consideration that is not something really safe to put jar's in your assets.

The above is:

- a good piece of information that adds value to the post
- not a commentary on any other post
- adds value to the post as a whole, because this information is not present in the other answer

I quote [Robert Cartaino](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino) from [this post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/a/218):

> Comments were designed to simply ask for clarification about the
> original question.
> Comments are such a light-weight mechanism, that
> putting useful information in there can actually be somewhat harmful:

- Comments cannot be properly vetted (voted on for correctness).
- The information in comments is not editable by the community.
- Comments are not easily searchable. When users are looking for your content, they are less likely to come here to find it.
- When users see that a question has been answered in comments, they are less likely to contribute proper answers.
- Questions with comment-based answers remain marked as "unanswered" by the system, so that does not bode well for the community. When someone asks a question, members of the community are supposed to propose answers.

The above post is not a commentary on any other post or a request for clarification. It adds information which is important, and is not present in the post.

Is this a valid answer, or is it "not an answer" (and hence eligible for deletion)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: If comments are simply meant to ask for clarification, then how does one critique a post? Is this comment invalid? (I think I'm asking for clarification so I might be safe...)

Comment: I think, its just a suggestion. The answer doesn't tell _why_. OP just says something that can just be added as a comment to post, to warn Asker about some behavior. Answer could have been added with more explanation about why, but that would also have been totally un-related answer to OP's question.

Comment: @JanDvorak, this is not a case of a link-only answer

Comment: @remyabel your comment asks for a clarification, so it's fine. Only OP is allowed to reply to you, though, and only through an edit. So, my comment is bad and hypocritical^KK ironic.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion the question doesn't cover link-only answers only

Comment: @Jan I believe that's known as [hypocritical humor.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HypocriticalHumor)

Comment: @remyabel there goes another day of my free time... :-)

Comment: @remyabel more specifically, it's a case of a [hypocrisy nod](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HypocrisyNod)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### ```
Should good information be posted as an answer or comment?
```

This is kind of subjective and is difficult to account for a objective viewpoint without riding a tour through the pros and cons of such information being posted within those mediums. So let's do that!

### Why are good information posted as an answer?

**New users** ► The author may have something crucial to add, but *does not have [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)* to comment. Their only act would be to post an edit or as an answer.
  — These users are new to the system and the information they attempt to add *and* the comment they entitle to are not appalling to reviewers; Good edits may convince such reviewers to verify the information and approve, but most of these explanation edits and additional notes are often radical and **Rejected** for "attempt to reply - This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. **It should have been written as a comment** or an answer."
 **[Entitlement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entitlement)** ► The author wants to *add something helpful* into the post under their name, but were not aware that [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107/3622940) and that answers exists to add solutions, not to bring up discussions, critique for information, or to add link-only answers to relevant tutorials.
  — Some users who are new and are not aware for this also attempt to add information in answers instead of comments for the reputation gain from upvoting - upvotes on answers rewards you with reputation, where comments don't.

**What about having information posted as an answer over a comment?**

1. It's **not an answer** - answers are for adding solutions to the question. It will be flagged and reviewers may use the review comment, which hopefully teaches users not to do this, however the "This is a comment" review comment doesn't really help:

   > #### This is commentary on another post, not an answer
   >
   > “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.”

(lolwhat? I'm not even critiquing or asking for clarification? This is information, you know?)

2. It sets a poor example. While it gets the attention it deserves with its own box over a comment, its existence gives the message that posting such information as an answer is acceptable, which is not the signal which should be given.
3. It may not necessarily be as helpful - **The information may contribute to the thread**, but not as a solution worthy of being in an answer box. For example, take in this case:

[image]
Walkthrough: The accepted answer answers the question, and does it well. The other three answers adds helpful information, but **isn't an answer**. Whether my answer has a score of zero or -1 is up to you, as the posts are sorted to votes, but for sure the entire thread would be much cleaner and nicer if the other three posts are left as comments on the question or the accepted answer. Right?

### [What if](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=mc_DZDrcX1IFuP7v0aO_3g2) good information is posted as a comment?

- It's buried in the comment thread.

  1. Firstly, while users may upvote the information, comment threads are folded and will not be as easily seen.
  2. Comments are comments, visitors don't read comments when going for help, they just read answers, get the answer and runs away. So it's not constructive this way.
- The comment will include the comment poster's name in the wrapper, allowing other users to quickly recognize the credibility of a link, based on the posters' reputation count. (Not that reputation has positive correlation with experience, however it is a slightly reliable guide.)

#### ```
The suitable way out for good information
```

- Write an actual answer - Hopefully helpful as well.
- Include your information in the post *as a footer*:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is **not an answer**. It should be a comment on the question; a comment on the top answer; or else edited into an answer. On its own, it does not answer the question.

Comment: NAA makes it eligible for deletion via LQP queue, so the information is lost permanently. If it should be a comment, then should it be flagged for mod attention? As it happened in this case, the information is lost.

Comment: It's still visible to high rep users. And since you brought it up here, it can easily be put into a comment.

Comment: I think in other cases, you could mention it to the OP, and if they don't, make the comment yourself.